# Get the direction, its superior and its inferior from the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table containing this columns :
t_socab : Never Mind
T_stro : Direction ID
c_stro : Never mind
Desi_stro : Direction name
T_strosup : Id of the superior direction

[image]

I want an sql request that can help me getting this columns :
Desi_stro : Direction name
Desi_sup : ID or name of superior direction
Desi_inf :Id or name of every inferior Direction

Well my problem is how to do an inner join from the same table,
if it was a link between two table it will be much easier.
Any help and thanks

Comment: Joining to a table to itself is no different to joining to any other table.

Comment: Well, i didn't reach the result

Comment: So show us your attempt in the question.

Comment: @zarzou please provide your sample result set that you expect from this sample dataset you already provided here.

Answer (score 0):

> Well my problem is how to do an inner join from the same table

Something like this:

```sql
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS ID,'AA'AS VALL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID,'BB'AS VALL
   UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 AS ID,'CC'AS VALL
)
SELECT C.ID,C.VALL
FROM CTE AS C
JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.ID>C2.ID
```

Comment: Sry but I didn't understand the first line

Comment: It is just a pseudo-table to show join. You can replace it with your table something like SELECT T.* FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS T2 ON T.ID>T2.ID